# Young Tableau Box Correlations

Tags: pr.probability, rt.representation-theory, permutation-groups, young-tableaux

Let $T$ be a uniformly random Standard Young Tableau (SYT) of shape $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_k)$ with $|\lambda|=n$. Let $T_{ij}$ denote the value in box $(i,j)$. I'm interested in what can be said about correlations like $P(T_{ij}=x,T_{kl}=y)$. Very roughly speaking, if $|\lambda|=n$ is quite large and the $\lambda_i$'s are also large, then I would expect that $P(T_{ij}=x,T_{kl}=y)\approx P(T_{ij}=x)P(T_{kl}=y)$ for $(i,j)$ far apart from $(k,l)$ and for $x,y$ "not unreasonable" (see next part).

As a working example lets just take a square partition $\lambda=(n,n,\cdots,n)$ with $|\lambda|=n^2$. We know that such a partition has a [well defined limit shape](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405190), so that if $x\approx an^2,y\approx bn^2$, then we expect $x,y$ to fall on limit curves, via what's more-or-less a semicircle distribution, i.e. being more likely to to fall near the middle of the limit curve than at the ends. My question is, on what scales do we know the error term $\delta$ of:

$$P(T_{ij}=x,T_{kl}=y)=P(T_{ij}=x)P(T_{kl}=y)+\delta_{ij,kl}(x,y)?$$

In other words, what does $\delta$ look like for $x,y=\Omega(n^2)$ and in particular when $|x-y|=o(n^2)$ or $|i-k|^2+|j-l|^2=o(n)$? Specifically, what is the order of $\delta$ in terms of $n$ and $(i,j),(k,l)$?.
I'm purposely leaving  a lot of room for interpretation because I'm guessing overall these are very difficult questions to answer for all possible cases of $x,y$.

Comment: There are plenty of results for correlation functions of random lozenge tilings/planar partitions (those are essentially the same); have you looked up that literature? (Borodin, Okunkov, Kenyon are relevant key authors). In the frozen region you have long range correlation, so I would not expect decorrelation as in the OP.

Comment: @oferzeitouni: I'm familiar with the mentioned lozenge tiling results but unfortunately I'm not sure if they apply here. Specifically, lozenge tilings use Plancherel measure whereas this problem is for uniform measure on a fixed tableau. As well, as far as I remember, schur functions and macdonald polynomials index lozenge tile locations and don't really rely on exact single box distributions. The only connection I see to Plancherel measure is that the resulting square limit curves are in some sense deformed Logan-Shepp curves.